# Está surgindo☺♥♦♣ no Rstudio. Isto é um bug?

Tags: r

Quando realizo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> para executar o comando no script, ocasionalmente, é inserido no meu script `☺`, `♥`, `♦` e `♣`. Isso é algum má configuração do rstudio ou um bug deste IDE?

Comment: Parece que isso acontece [desde 2013](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200644706-Shortcut-ctrl-alt-e-adds-accented-character) com alguns usuários.